# NativeScript lockdown (or kiosk) application

Tags: android, nativescript

I wondering if it is possible to create a "*lockdown*" application with NativeScript.

My aim is to place an android tablet in a public area where people may only interact with my NativeScript application:

- fullscreen
- no home-button access
- no sleep/standby
- no notification bar

Then, if possible, a pin code may allow to unlock the application.

Example:

[image: like this]

Comment: Do you want to lock the phone with device default screen lock Or you want to build your own lock screen?

Comment: Maybe "lockdown application" is not the right term. I need an application that is always visible fullscreen, never in sleep mode, where uses cannot go anywhere else (it is like a lockdown screen)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for kiosk app, it's of course possible with NativeScript.

You will have to access android's native apis to do so, [here](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu) are some heads up.

Also there is a [thread](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/android-kiosk-mode-single-app-mode/3186/4?u=manojdcoder) in the forums which will give you some initial thoughts on doing this with NativeScript.